# Xcode4: Profiling Unit Tests

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, profiling, xcode-instruments

I have an Xcode project with a framework target and a separate target for unit tests. Since there is no executable target I can't run the profiling tools without creating a new target, linking against the framework and profiling it that way. However, this means I have to move a lot of code around which unreliable and annoying.

Is there a way I can run the profiling tools (mainly Allocations) on my testing target?